# Create a ggplot barchart/histogram with fill and outline colors indicated by different variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to create a chart in ggplot along these lines:

[image]

...in which the color of the boxes is indicated by one variable, and the outline of the boxes is indicated by another variable.

Assuming the data is structured like this:

```
df<-data.frame(index=1:50,date=sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('1999/06/01'), by="day"), 50,replace=T),
           V1=sample(c("Indigenous","Import-related","Imported","Unknown"), 50,replace=T),
           V2=sample(c(NA,"Zombie","Pulmonary Hemorrhage"), 50,replace=T))
```

All I can think of is something like this:

```
require(ggplot2)
#draw the histogram with fill determined by V1
p<-ggplot(data=df)+geom_histogram(aes(x=date,group=V1,fill=V1),binwidth=7,color="black",alpha=0.9)
#draw the individual boxes for each case
p1<-p+scale_fill_discrete()+geom_histogram(aes(x=date,group=index),binwidth=7,color="black",alpha=0)
#attempt to draw green boxes for one value of V2
p2<-p1+geom_histogram(aes(x=date,group=V2=="Zombie"),binwidth=7,color="green",alpha=0,size=1.2)
#attempt to draw orange boxes for the other value of V2
p3<-p2+geom_histogram(aes(x=date,group=V2=="Pulmonary Hemorrhage"),binwidth=7,color="orange",alpha=0,size=1.2)
```

However, this is not working as it draws borders everywhere and I cannot isolate individual cases using this approach, as you can see.

[image]

Is there a ggplot solution? If I can't do colored boxes, I could indicate V2 by some kind of text annotation on the appropriate boxes, but then would have to figure out x and y for each label, and that's giving me fits as well.

Comment: date V1, V2 combination gives 1 record per combination, can you check your dataset please?

Comment: @Hardikgupta, thanks - not sure what you mean though. Is it a problem that there are not more than one case with the same combination of date, V1 and V2? That seems reasonable to me in this example. But if it helps you think about the question I will add a dataset in which there are guaranteed to be at least 2 records per combination. (separate comment)

Comment: @Hardikgupta: try using this code, which will give you at least 2 cases per combination of variables. Though I'd be grateful if you could please let me know why this matters! `df2<-data.frame(index=1:25,date=seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('1999/01/01')+24, by="day"),
               V1=sample(c("Indigenous","Import-related","Imported","Unknown"), 50,replace=T),
               V2=sample(c(NA,"Zombie","Pulmonary Hemorrhage"), 50,replace=T))

df<-rbind(df2,df2)`

Answer (score 0):

We can try like this

```
df<-data.table(index=1:50,date=sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('1999/06/01'), by="day"), 50,replace=T),
               V1=sample(c("Indigenous","Import-related","Imported","Unknown"), 50,replace=T),
               V2=sample(c(NA,"Zombie","Pulmonary Hemorrhage"), 50,replace=T))

df <- df[,.(count=.N), by = .(date,V1,V2)]

windows()
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = date, y = count, color = V2, fill = V1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", width = 2, size = 1) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red4", "blue4", "green4", "blue")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("orange", "green", "black")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(1,3,1))
```

Comment: Thanks Hardik - though I'm looking for a binned histogram within a 7 day interval. The other visual problem here is that adjacent bars overlap with each other, so it's difficult to read.